# Removing ID from JSON then adding it into each set of data.

Tags: python, json

I have been running a Python script that removes the ID for each set of data to allow it to upload to BigQuery. Now instead of removing this information I want to insert it into each set of data so I can reference it later on.

This is how I have been receiving the JSON that I upload to Bigquery along with the code.

```
{"AppName": "DataWorks", "foundedPeripheralCount": 1, "version": "1.6.1(8056)", "deviceType": "iPhone 6", "createdAt": "2017-04-05T07:05:30.408Z", "updatedAt": "2017-04-05T07:08:49.569Z", "connectedPeripheralCount": 1, "iOSVersion": "10.2.1"}
```

-

```
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://dataworks-356fa.firebaseio.com/')
result = firebase.get('/PeripheralCount', None)
id_keys = map(str, result.keys()) #filter out ID names


with open("firetobq_peripheral2.json", "w") as outfile:
  for id in id_keys:
    json.dump(result[id], outfile, indent=None)
    outfile.write("\n")
```

This is how the JSON is created without any edits along with the code.

```
{"1972FDEE-E2C0-4E8C-BD00-630315D4AEDE": {"AppName": "DataWorks", "foundedPeripheralCount": 1, "version": "1.6.1(8056)", "deviceType": "iPhone 6", "connectedPeripheralCount": 1, "updatedAt": "2017-04-05T07:08:49.569Z", "Peripherals": {"1CA726ED-32B1-43B4-9071-B58BBACE20A8": "Arduino"}, "createdAt": "2017-04-05T07:05:30.408Z", "iOSVersion": "10.2.1"}
```

Where `1972FDEE-E2C0-4E8C-BD00-630315D4AEDE` is the ID.

```
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://dataworks-356fa.firebaseio.com/')
result = firebase.get('/PeripheralCount', None)
id_keys = map(str, result.keys()) #filter out ID names


with open("firetobq_peripheralx.json", "w") as outfile:
  # for id in id_keys:
  json.dump(result, outfile, indent=None)
  outfile.write("\n")
```

I would like it to look something like this though.

```
{"ID": "1972FDEE-E2C0-4E8C-BD00-630315D4AEDE", "AppName": "DataWorks", "foundedPeripheralCount": 1, "version": "1.6.1(8056)", "deviceType": "iPhone 6", "connectedPeripheralCount": 1, "updatedAt": "2017-04-05T07:08:49.569Z", "Peripherals": {"1CA726ED-32B1-43B4-9071-B58BBACE20A8": "Arduino"}, "createdAt": "2017-04-05T07:05:30.408Z", "iOSVersion": "10.2.1"}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First define a base `dict` to save your ID:

```
out = {
    "ID": "1972FDEE-E2C0-4E8C-BD00-630315D4AEDE",
}
```

Then, update `out` with the origin JSON:

```
out.update(js_dict.get(out.get('ID')))
```

js_dict is the JSON you mentioned above.